# angularjs data binding issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to allow a user to submit a comment, where it can be displayed. However, It doesn't seem to be working properly as I am able to get it to displayed as a preview but when I submit, it does not save as an array where the other comments are held. After debugging, I found out it was binding to my $scope.review, but it was being submitted to my array as a blank default format as shown on the webpage. The source code can be found at http://plnkr.co/edit/q5fRIG6DzTegi3Ir1y8G?p=preview. (Commented out the resetting of pristine state and scope, which also gives same error).

Javascript

```
    .controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.review = {name:"", rating:"Five", comment:"",date:""};
            $scope.submitComment = function () {

            $scope.review.date = new Date().toISOString();

            //  Push comment into the dish's comment array
            $scope.dish.comments.push("$scope.review");
             //reset  form to pristine
           // $scope.commentForm.$setPristine="";
             //reset  JavaScript object that holds your comment
           // $scope.review = {name:"", rating:"Five", comment:"",date:""};
        }
```

Html

```
        <div class="media-list">
                <ul ng-show="!commentForm.comment.$error.required && !commentForm.comment.$pristine && !commentForm.name.$error.required && !commentForm.name.$pristine">
                    <blockquote>
                        <p>{{review.rating}} Stars</p>
                        <p>{{review.comment}}</p>
                        <footer>By {{review.name}} on {{review.date | date:'mediumDate'}} </footer>
                    </blockquote>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Lucas, you need to add the object rather than the string. Also your new review field names don't match the existing fields in the existing reviews

```
.controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.review = {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"",
                                   author:"",
                                   date:""
                               };
                $scope.submitComment = function () {

                $scope.review.date = new Date().toISOString();

                //  Push comment into the dish's comment array
                $scope.dish.comments.push($scope.review);
                 //reset  form to pristine
                $scope.commentForm.$setPristine="";
                 //reset  JavaScript object that holds your comment
                $scope.review = {author:"", rating:5, comment:"",date:""};
            }

        }])
```

Notice I modified the "name" to "author" and the rating value from "Five" to 5. You will need to check the bindings in the "preview" html to match the changes though!

modified plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zzJUivzpSNLTFk0tltjD?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the bug just by matching my properties with that from my other controller. Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to push the object:

```
$scope.dish.comments.push($scope.review);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing a string, whereas you need to push an object:

```
$scope.dish.comments.push($scope.review);
```

Also, `$scope.dish.comments` belong to `DishDetailController`. The `submitComment` method belongs to `DishCommentController`. The scope is controller defined, so they won't know about the existence of eachother.

You need to put the methods in the same controller if you are expecting to share scope